# Set default Page on IIS 10 for Error with StatusCode 404.20

Tags: asp.net, iis-10, websecurity

I am getting HTTP Error 404.20 - Not Found for the below Url. Whereas the expectation is to display any custom Error page .

> `https://localhost/mysite/dataw/yyyyy/%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E`

Comment: "Whereas the expectation is to display any custom Error page", so what's that? If you don't configure a custom error page on IIS, it won't automatically serve a custom page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404.20 error means `Too Many URL Segments`, I found that the URL requested in your screenshot is too long, you can specify the maximum number of segments permitted in a URL through the [maxurlSegments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/limits#attributes) property.

[image]